# python parsing url parameters into a dictionary with urllib

Tags: python, parsing, url, parameters, urllib

I am trying to get the parameters of a url using urllib.

After revisiting some StackOverflow Q&A there are answers under these lines:

from urllib.parse import urlparse

```
url2='https://batavia.flyingcar.org/dfr/?d=34?f=56#/?dossier=ZT18174#/?dossier2=ZZ274'
parsed = urlparse(url2)
print(parsed)
```

The result is:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='batavia.internal.epo.org', path='/digital-file-repository/', params='', query='d=34?f=56', fragment='/?dossier=ZT1880174#/?dossier2=ZZ2221880174')
```

In order to get all the parameters I might used:

```
print(parsed.params)
print(parsed.query)
print(parsed.fragment)
```

Result:

```
d=34?f=56
/?dossier=ZT18174#/?dossier2=ZZ274
```

My questions:
a) why params is nothing?
b) Is there any function to get the results in form of a dictionary without having to parse the strings?
c) Why is fragment treated differently as query if both are meant to pass parameters?

Answer (score 0):

First, the URLs shouldn't have multiple `?` in them, subsequent parameters are separated by `&`. That URL is just broken.

a) param is always empty, it's even documented as "always an empty string"

b) you can use `urllib.parse.parse_qs()` to split the query string into a dict but it will not work if you have multiple `?` in the query string

c) parsing params from the fragment is just a convention, the fragment is everything after `#` and does not have any standard encoding convention.